# Tensorflow Confirm that Weights are Frozen

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, neural-network

I'm trying to freeze some layers in a neural network so that the weights do not change. How can I confirm that my weights are not being updated?

Is there some way I can view the weights or plot them? Perhaps in Tensorboard?

Using Python and Tensorflow 1.x by the way.

Comment: Train the model on some data. Now, get the weights of the model and the frozen weights ( before training ), compare them with `tf.equals`. If they both are equal then the weights weren't updated.

Comment: @ShubhamPanchal Thanks! Do you know if I can also plot it somehow?

Comment: If you are using `keras Model` you can print `model.summary()` before and after freezing which will print out the number of trainable and non-trainable parameters.